# Soliciting Selected Answers

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

Is it appropriate to ask the OP of a question to select your answer as the selected answer when you know that s/he has entirely understood your answer and that s/he is satisifed by it in the comments?

For example: [in this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/76572/29011) I completely explained the mechanics of the pulley sliding on the table and one can see that this accurately answers the OP's questions from the comments. Is it okay for me to remind the OP to choose my answer as the selected answer?

Comment: I usually remind them politely that they can upvote and accept answers they found useful, and link them to the [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) help page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's perfectly fine and even encouraged to remind a poster of SE etiquette, in particular that they should upvote helpful answers and accept the best one that directly answered their question, if there is one. But it's not OK to *tell* someone how to vote or which answer to accept.

To take the actual example from the answer you're asking about, the comment you posted:

> Also, since you've understood the answer, mark this as this as the accepted answer by clicking the checkbox on side.

is not appropriate. But this would be fine:

> If you think this is the best answer, could you mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkbox on the side?

This isn't something that gets you in trouble just for doing it once, but if we notice someone *repeatedly* making the former sort of comment (telling people how to vote), that will probably be the basis for some sort of disciplinary action.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the answer. I apologize for the lack of good wording in my comment! But, is it okay to ask the OP once again to mark my answer? I don't want to be mistaken for spamming a comment thread with "pick me!" comments.

Comment: I'd say a good rule of thumb is that a new poster should get no more than one reminder per answer about accepting an answer, and not more than a few total. Except that if you think the OP didn't notice your earlier comment, it's okay to point it out one more time.

Comment: Cool, yeah, I think the OP didn't regard my previous comment because it was in between a long comment thread. Marking this answer as selected :)